# Trace mail status

Tags: trace, email, html-email, email-spam

Hello i am making an application in which i want to know that what i have mailed through my application to some mail id. Is that open or not by that person

example

> My Application -> mail send ->to -> xyz@xyz.com -> received or not and if received than i want to know that the
>   person opened it or not or delete or retain. or its in span or inbox

Main thing is i want to trace the mail how i do it i dont understand how do i trace it what i have done is

```
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$name=$_POST["name"];
$mail=$_POST["mail"];
$message=$_POST["message"];
$subject="Vivek Moyal In";
$data="<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<table border=1>
<tr><td class='main'>Name</td><td>:</td><td>$name</td></tr>
<tr><td class='main'>Mail Id</td><td>:</td><td>$mail</td></tr>
<tr><td class='main'>Message</td><td>:</td><td>$message</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>";
$to="vivek@simplyitsols.com";

mail($to, $subject, $data,$headers);

if(mail)
{
    echo 'Thanks For sending message';
}
 else {
    echo 'Please try again';
}
```

Mail is perfect according to the code but i want to trace it

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Email doesn't provide an ability to do that.

There are two approaches that *could* work in *some* situations, but they have drawbacks:

- you could ask for read receipt, but if the mail client doesn't implement it or if the user doesn't want to send it, then you won't ever get it
- you could embed a tracking image in your HTML mail, but if the mail client doesn't show images (which is often the default these days), then again: you won't see anything.

And if the mail lands in the SPAM folder or not is entirely untrackable from the sender side.

Comment: let me tell you what i am making is the bulk email sender so i need to know about the status of the mail is there any other

Comment: Oh, if that's what you are doing then suddenly all the fact are ... still exactly the same as before: It's still not possible to do reliably. You can get *some* feedback, but you can't tell for sure.

Comment: Also: if you have a legitimate reason to send bulk mail, then get ask one of the companies that specializes in that: there are *tons* of things that can go wrong and they have the experience. If you have **no** legitimate reason then: don't spam.

Comment: You'd really have to control the SMTP server for this to work at all. At [PostageApp](http://postageapp.com), we send to SMTP servers and all we can tell is if we have successfully delivered the email to the SMTP server. You can put in open and click tracking, but that's as far as you can reliably go.

Comment: @JonLim: you'd have to control *all* SMTP servers for this. And that *still* wouldn't be sufficient. Just because a mail has been delivered to the users computer doesn't mean he has seen it, let alone read it.

Comment: @Joachim: Yes, I agreed with my original post. That's why I added open and click tracking, but those are the most reliable solutions Vivek can possibly have, but you've already pointed out the issues with them!

Comment: How i can track it through the image i dont get you